# Multiple WordPress Standard Galleries on a page stop images being displayed from other page galleries

Tags: gallery

I'm using the [simple gallery shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) in my WordPress site to add galleries to my page, but I'm adding multiple galleries to the same page.

`[gallery link="file" columns="4" ids="2501,2500, 2499, 2498" size="thumbnail"]`

Then I have another one further on in the same page:

`[gallery link="file" columns="3" ids="2602,524,45,4" size="thumbnail"]`

When the either of the galleries is opened it is possible to scroll to through the other galleries images. Is there a way to have unique galleries on the page that don't show images from other galleries also sharing the page?

Comment: WordPress doesn't have a way to "open" galleries. Clicking an image just links directly to the image file, which will be opened by the browser. If some sort of pop-up or page is opening that lets you scroll through images, then that's been added by your theme or a plugin. So any solution to this would depend on what that is. If you can figure that out you'll need to ask its author if you can do this.

Comment: It appears the wordpress doc https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode suggests that the gallery is not added by your theme or a plugin, but built in to the core wordpress code.

Comment: That’s not what I said. Read my comment again. It’s the “opening” of galleries with scrolling that’s added by a plugin.